# UIWebView not loading after being pushed onto a UINavigationController via clicking a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

Trying to load www.google.com using a WebView that has a subclassed UIViewController that is instantiated from my storyboard. It is to be pushed onto the screen when a UITableViewCell is clicked.

I'm using the following code, but I only get a white screen. Please help.

(I have no errors)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    _webViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];

    [_webViewController.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this won't work...

try the last line ([_webViewController.webView loadRequest:request];) in _webViewController itself..